# How to get the sql connection from dts config file in ssis package scripts

Tags: c#, sql-server, ssis, script-task, ssis-connection-manager

In our normal c# this is the way to get connection string from `app.config`

```
SqlConnection con = 
new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DPTConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
```

But how will achieve the same in vsts scripts using dts config file.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/integration-services/extending-packages-scripting/task/connecting-to-data-sources-in-the-script-task?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: You might have to create ADO.Net connection that connects to your SQL database and then use that in the script task then you should be able to connect to that database. I think we can't do the same if have the OLE DB conn.

Comment: @NAGARAJAHI why not accepting answers??

Answer (score 1):

Inside a Script Task you can use the `Dts` namespace to retrieve connections; you should use the `Connections` property and execute the AcquireConnection function to retrieve the relevant`SqlConnection` class *(You need to perform a explicit cast operation in order to do that)* as example:

```
 SqlConnection myOLEDBConnection = Dts.Connections["OLEDB Connection"].AcquireConnection(Dts.Transaction) as SqlConnection;
```

For flat files, connection use the same logic but the result is a string:

```
string FFConnection = Dts.Connections["FlatFile Connection"].AcquireConnection(Dts.Transaction) as string;
```

Comment: is Data Source=BDC11-L-7171TPV;Integrated Security=SSPI;Initial Catalog=CSMLogging example of OLEDB Connection

Comment: Yes that is true